# Is Spock's father played by the same actor as the first Romulan Captain seen on set?

Tags: star-trek

Is the first Romulan seen on set (Episode 15 "Balance of Terror" of Season 1) played by the same actor as Spock's Father (Episode 10 "Journey to Babel" Season 2)?

The two characters look completely identical, other than a difference in clothing. When watching "Journey of Babel" and seeing Spock's father I instantly recognized the face and I think that they may of re-cycled the actor.

Comment: Seriously?  You didn't go straight to IMDB to check who played Sarek and who played the Romulan Commander?  Yikes.

Comment: @T-5000: perhaps he's just never heard of IMDB?  http://xkcd.com/1053/

Comment: For future reference, answers to this sort of question can often be found on the websites imdb.com or tv.com.  (I can't link to them for some reason; are they blacklisted here?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston- But he has a web browser and knows about scifi.stackexchange.  I would bet he knows about that "Google" thing too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Both characters described were played by the same actor, [Mark Lenard](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0501697/?ref_=tt_cl_t5#actor-tt0060028). However, it's not technically correct to say that he was the "first" Romulan seen in TOS.

[Mark Lenard](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0501697/?ref_=tt_cl_t5#actor-tt0060028) is credited as Sarek in "Journey to Babel" and as "Romulan Commander" in "Balance of Terror". According to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mark_Lenard), Lenard is technically the *second* Romulan seen on-screen:

> Lenard is often credited as being the first ever Romulan to appear in *Star Trek*; however, by strict order of screen appearance, that honor falls to Lawrence Montaigne as Decius, who appeared seconds before Lenard but was wearing a helmet covering his Romulan ears.

Lenard as Sarek:

[image: Sarek]

And as a Romulan:
[image: Romulan Commander]

As an amusing aside, in addition to playing the first (recognizable) Romulan in *Star Trek*, Lenard also holds the double honour of playing the first Klingon with the post-TOS forehead ridges and the first to speak the constructed Klingon language; Lenard played a Klingon captain in *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*:

[image: Klingon]